# Node.js sending an email with image attachment using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, email, express, node-modules, nodemailer

I'm trying to send an email from a post request. I'm using Express and nodemailer. I'm confused by 'fs' My email is getting sent but the image is not included as an attachment. I checked the docs but they all seem to send up static files not files being streamed in from a form request.

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
  service: "Gmail",
  auth: {
    user: "gmail_address@gmail.com",
    pass: "password_for_gmail_address"
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'
      + '<p>Post Title: <input type="text" name="title"/></p>'
      + '<p>Post Content: <input type="text" name="content"/></p>'
      + '<p>Image: <input type="file" name="image"/></p>'
      + '<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>'
      + '</form>');
  })

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
  var mailOptions = {
    from: "gmail_address@gmail.com", // sender address
    to: "somebodyelse@example.com", // list of receivers
    subject: req.body.title, // Subject line
    text: req.body.content, // plaintext body
    attachments:[
      {
        fileName: req.body.title,
        streamSource: req.files.image
      }
    ]
  }

  smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
      res.send('Failed');
    }else{
      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
      res.send('Worked');
    }
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `req.files.image` is a [`File`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable#formidablefile) object, not a readable stream, you'd need to create a read stream for it that you can use in the attachment:

```
streamSource: fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path)
```

Comment: I made the attachments object look like this 'attachments:[
      {
        fileName: req.body.title+".jpg",
        streamSource: fs.createReadStream(req.files.image.path)
      }
    ]'

Answer (score 6):

this worked for me:

```
attachments: [{   // stream as an attachment
            filename: 'image.jpg',
            content: fs.createReadStream('/complete-path/image.jpg')
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `streamSource` try using `contents`

```
contents: new Buffer(req.files.image, 'base64')
```

Comment: This got it in as an attachment but it wasn't treated as an image by my email client. I think it could work but not as copy paste easy as JohnnyHK's answer - Thanks though!